# Lambda function error scanning dynamo db table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function that scans and performs put/delete item operations on a dynamodb table.

When my lambda executes, I get the following exception:

```
Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxx:table/my_table because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Scan action
```

The policy that is attached to the role that the lambda function is executed under contains the following statement:

```
        {
        "Sid": "AllowDynamoDBActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxx:table/my_table"
        ]
    }
```

Any idea on what the issue may be? I originally had the Scan permission declared explicitly, but that wasn't working either, so I just decided to try allowing everything, still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you trying to use an index?  If so, you'll need permission to access that index as well.  See <https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this existing policy to the role that is used to execute the Lambda function. That should work and I have never seen an issue when using this.

[image]

Comment: i started from scratch and added that, seemed to work. thanks

Comment: The out of box ones seem to work better

Comment: I would advise *against* using `DynamoDBFullAccess`.  That role is an over-permissioned disaster: it can not only do anything at all with DynamoDB (including delete your database), but it can also create or delete arbitrary Lambda functions, change the permissions on arbitrary SNS Topics, and a bunch of other things.  You should give your application only the specific permissions that it actually needs.